# How to concatenate pdf filename in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, loops

I cannot use graphicspath for including pdf files in figure environment so I need to concatenate filenames as following but I do not know how to concatenate a string with an integer, leading to the string

```
{{{/home/masi/1/\nameid}.pdf}}
```

Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{graphics}        

\begin{document}
\foreach \nameid in {1, .., 10} {

\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{{{/home/masi/1/\nameid}.pdf}}
\end{figure}

} % closing brace for loop 

\end{document}
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: why can't you use graphics path? but what you have used will also work if you remove the spurious extra `{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there some reason you are using `graphics` and not `graphicx`? You have extra brackets in your filepath. Remove them and it should work as you expect. Also, you're missing `.` in the `\foreach` statement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{graphicx}        

\begin{document}
\foreach \nameid in {1,...,10} {

\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{/home/masi/1/\nameid}
\end{figure}

} % closing brace for loop 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I think the extra bracket should not lead to a complication. It is there, because sometimes, I have underscores in filenames.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 A pair of curly braces is only automatically removed, if it surround an argument that is read by a macro. Otherwise, the curly braces are staying as group, math subformula or part of the file name.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 the extra brackets will not lead to a complication they are just taken very literally and the system  will look for a file with brackets in its name. The brackets have no effect at all on underscores.